# Conditioning on two events

Tags: probability

I know the following formula:

$$P(A \mid B) = \dfrac{P(A , B)}{P(B)} \tag 1$$

what I do not understand is why if we condition on C we have the following equation:

$$P(A \mid B,C) = \dfrac{P(A , B \mid C)}{P(B\mid C)} \tag 2 $$

why can't it be in analogy with (1) rather:

$$P(A \mid B,C) = \dfrac{P(A , B , C)}{P(B,C)}\tag 3$$

?

Thanks

Comment: Rights hand sides of (2) and (3) are equal. Use (1) to go from (2) to (3).

Comment: Ah indeed! And I was thinking for so long not seeing that! thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $(2)$ and $(3)$ are correct. You might use $(2)$ if you know something about conditional probabilities given $C$.

All probabilities are conditional.  In $(1)$, the events $A$ and $B$ are subsets of some larger probability space (or you might know it as a "sample space"), which let us call $\Omega$. Thus you can write $(1)$ as
$$
P(A \mid B,\Omega) = \dfrac{P(A , B\mid\Omega)}{P(B\mid\Omega)}
$$
and then it looks just like $(2)$.

You can write $(3)$ as
$$
P(A \mid B,C,\Omega) = \dfrac{P(A , B , C\mid\Omega)}{P(B,C\mid\Omega)}\
$$
and then it also looks like $(2)$.  (On the left side, $\text{“}\Omega\text{''}$ is redundant since $B,C\subseteq\Omega$.)

Comment: many thanks!...